# My code isn't working when I call the methods from Retail Class

Tags: python

I'm trying to display the information from the following methods but its not displaying. This based on question below. Also, I changed the names of the units inventory.

Write a class named that holds data about an item in a retail store. The class should RetailItem store the following data in attributes: item description, units in inventory & price.

Once you have written the class, write a program that creates three objects and RetailItem stores the following data in them:

```
Description        Units in Inventory       Price Item   
Item #1               Jacket                 59.95
Item #2             Designer Jeans           34.95
Item #3             Shirt 20                 24.95


class Retail_Item:
     def __init__(self, item_description, units_in_inventory, price):
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.units_in_inventory = units_in_inventory
        self.price = price

     def item_description(self):
         return self.item_description

     def units_in_inventory(self):
         return self.units_in_inventory

     def price(self):
         return self.price
import retail_items

def main():
    retail=retail_items.Retail_Item("Jacket","12","59.95")
    retail_2=retail_items.Retail_Item("GUCCI","14","34.95")
    retail_3=retail_items.Retail_Item("LEVIS","15","24.95")

    print("Description:",retail.item_description())
    print("Price:",retail.units_in_inventory())
    print("Units in Inventory:",retail.price())
    print()
    print("Description:",retail_2.item_description())
    print("Price:",retail_2.units_in_inventory())
    print("Units in Inventory:",retail_2.price())
    print()
    print("Description:",retail_3.item_description())
    print("Price:",retail_3.units_in_inventory())
    print("Units in Inventory:",retail_3.price())

main()
```

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: What do you think `import retail_items` is supposed to do? Is the class `Retail_Item` part of the same file as `main()`? Then you can just instantiate directly: `Retail_Item(..)`.

Comment: don't use the same name for variable `self.price` and for methods `def price(self)`  because (for Python) it is the same element. (the same with other variables in your class.) In Python mostly we use only variable `self.price` without creating methods to get value `def price(self)`.

Comment: Python isn't Java.  If the only purpose of the `price()` method is to access the price variable, why use a method at all?  Just access the variable directly: `retail.price`

Comment: @GinoMempin I assume the code is actually arranged into two separate modules, `retail_items.py` and `main.py`, but the question didn't make that clear.

Comment: print("Description:",retail.item_description())

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.... This is the traceback error

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because, for example, the method and member variable "item_description" both have the same name. Python cannot dinstinguish both. Therefore by calling `item.item_description()` you try to call the member variable like a function, which is not possible (Python tells you that via "str object is not callable").

3 possible solutions:

1. You could rename your member variables to e.g. m_item_description. That way python can distinguish both.

   3. Rename the Get-Method to e.g `ItemDec()`
2. Don't use a Get-Method at all, but access the member variable directly via `item.item_description` (don't use braces)